# Can We put the old version of the app as a new app on play store?

Tags: android, google-play, google-apps-marketplace

I have a question.
Lets Say: 
I have an app 
I put it on market.
I created an update that changed many features.
Now Can I upload the old version of that app (Changing the package name)
as a new app on Play Store?
Is this allowed or not?

Comment: you mean technically?

Comment: I mean If I Do,I don't want Google say Oh,You can't do that So we are suspending your application.
I want to know Can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is allowed. It's just a matter of naming this new (old) version of the app with a different package name.

Comment: The New Version of the app will be uploaded on the existing app on play store whereas the old version is going to be uploaded as a new app.

Comment: That's it. Definitely you Can do this. Thank you. EDIT: just to put some light into another side: this kind of thing (publish a new app from an old version of an existing app) even don't infringe Google App Store TOS.